# Установка breakpoint в Python через CPython API по номеру строки, не изменяя переданный код

Tags: python-3.x, c, ios, objective-c, swift3

Я разрабатываю IDE Python для IOS, а в любой IDE есть Debug, поэтому мне надо его реализовать. Читая разные источники, узнал, что в Python есть функция breakpoint(), однако ее надо встраивать в код, который будет передан на выполнения, следовательно мне надо самолично загрузить код из каждого файла и проставить breakpoint. Это не очень удобно для меня. Единственное, что я придумал - это бесконечный (до нажатие кнопки IDE "продолжить") while. Есть ли более, если можно сказать, красивее решения это проблемы?
P.S:

```
static int trace_function(PyObject *obj, PyFrameObject *frame, int event, PyObject *arg) {
// Проверяем событие, если это событие линии
if (event == PyTrace_LINE) {
    // Получаем текущий номер строки
    
    int current_line = PyFrame_GetLineNumber(frame);
    printf("Currently at line: %d\n", current_line);
    
    if (current_line == 2) {
        printf("Breakpoint at line: %d\n", current_line);
        while (1) {
            
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

эта функция передается в систему отслеживания выполнения Python.
Для примера цикл while просто бесконечный.